# Collect attribute property values

Tags: c#, code-generation, envdte, texttemplate

I apologize in advance if this gets a little convoluted.

I have an attribute class like so:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class RepositoryCollectionMethodAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string MethodName { get; set; }
    public RepositoryCollectionMethodAttribute(string methodName)
    {
        MethodName = methodName;
    }
}
```

I am traversing my class domain using `EnvDTE`, collecting classes for code generation.  Finding a class that decorates one or more properties with the `RepositoryCollectionMethod`.

This part was relatively easy, so for each class with *some* of these properties decorated, I now have an `IEnumerable<CodeProperty>` I call `properties`.

Now I'm stuck.  Due to the nature of these EnvDTE objects (which seem to have an aversion to strong typing and good documentation/ examples) I cannot figure out how to extract a distinct list of `MethodName` property values from the collection of properties, at least one of which will have a `RepositoryCollectionMethod` decorating it.

In other words, if I have a class `Foo' like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Guid FooId { get; set; }

    [RepositoryCollectionMethod("GetFoosByCategory")]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [RepositoryCollectionMethod("GetFoosByClass")]
    [RepositoryCollectionMethod("GetFoosByClassAndLot")]
    public string Class { get; set; }

    [RepositoryCollectionMethod("GetFoosByLot")]
    [RepositoryCollectionMethod("GetFoosByClassAndLot")]
    public string Lot { get; set; }

}
```

...given an `IEnumerable<CodeProperty>` of `Foo`'s properties, I would like to generate the following list:

- GetFoosByCategory
- GetFoosByClass
- GetFoosByClassAndLot
- GetFoosByLot

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: did you find any answer to this ?

Comment: Ended up going a completely different route;  Got crickets on this question.

Comment: how did you achieve that , can explain a bit if possible. ?

Comment: Basically I used a convention-based fluent method to define how I wanted my repository queries to build.